# need code for four checkboxes displaying msg for ten diferrent condition

Tags: vb.net

i have four checkboxes on winform , the user has to select from them on a predefined condition. That is, if the user  selecst chkbx1 or chkbx2 or chkbx3 or chkbx4 (any one of them), each selection has a diferrent msg to display.

2nd condition user can select any two chkbx e.g(chk1 +chkbx2,or chkbx1+chkbx3,or chkbx1+chkbx4), each selection hv diferrent msg to display.

3rd condition any three checkbox(chkbx 1+2+3 or 1+3+4,or1+2+4) can be selected. each selection hv diferrent msg to display

4th condition all four hv to select display msg on btnclck.......user hv to select at least one checkbox compulsory

i'm doing it with `if else statement`

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("U choose 1")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("U choose 2")
        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("U choose 3")
            If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
                MessageBox.Show("U choose 4")
                If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                    CheckBox4.Checked = True
                    MessageBox.Show("U choose 5")
                    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                        CheckBox4.Checked = True
                        MessageBox.Show("U choose 6")

                        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                            CheckBox4.Checked = True
                            CheckBox2.Checked = True
                            MessageBox.Show("U choose 7")
                            If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                                CheckBox4.Checked = True
                                CheckBox3.Checked = True

                                MessageBox.Show("U choose 8")
                                If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
                                    CheckBox4.Checked = True
                                    CheckBox2.Checked = True
                                    MessageBox.Show("U choose 9")
                                    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                                        CheckBox4.Checked = True
                                        CheckBox2.Checked = True
                                        CheckBox3.Checked = True
                                        MessageBox.Show("U choose 10")
                                    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                                        CheckBox4.Checked = False
                                        CheckBox2.Checked = False
                                        CheckBox3.Checked = False
                                        MessageBox.Show("select any one")

                                    End If

                                End If

                            End If



                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

on closing the msgbx another msg displayed and other chkbxss automatically selected

Comment: what's the switch for !?

Comment: Any code after Line 4 ( If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then)  will only be reached if CheckBox2 is checked and won't apply if not.  Is that what you want?  I guess not because there's another ( If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then) check further down.  Could you be clearer about the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some pointers. Are you a CS student? If so, you'll appreciate that my proposition includes some binary calculations. You see, you have 4 checkboxes, which means that you have 4² different possible outcomes. Doing this with embedded `If` will be awful to work with.
On the other hand, you can calculate the result you're lookinf for at the very point when the user is finished playing with the checkboxes. You could do this anyway you like. Here are 2 ways to achieve this:

```
Private Sub ShowResult()
    Select Case GetCheckboxesTotal()
        Case 0
            MessageBox.Show("0")
        Case 1
            MessageBox.Show("1")
        Case 2
            MessageBox.Show("2")
        Case 3
            '...
        Case 14
            MessageBox.Show("14")
        Case 15
            MessageBox.Show("15")
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function GetCheckboxesTotal() As Integer
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then total += 1
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then total += 2
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then total += 4
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then total += 8

    Return total
End Function
```

This solution uses the power of binary math! In this answer, each checkbox is a "bit", and the `GetCheckboxesTotal()` function calculate the exact combinaison your user checked, from no checkboxes (0) to all checkboxes (15). Notice that, as foretold, this makes for 16 distinct possibilities, which you can address in a nice `Select Case` where every possibility is treated once in a very readable manner.

Now, what if you don't like the mathematical part of this answer? No worries, friend, there's a very, very easy way to deal with this again:

```
Private Sub ShowResult()
    Select Case True
        Case Not CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox4.Checked
            MessageBox.Show("0")
        Case CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox4.Checked
            MessageBox.Show("1")
        Case Not CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox4.Checked
            MessageBox.Show("2")
        Case CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso Not CheckBox4.Checked
            '...
        Case Not CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso CheckBox4.Checked
            MessageBox.Show("14")
        Case CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso CheckBox4.Checked
            MessageBox.Show("15")
    End Select
End Sub
```

This manner of dealing with the 16 possible outcomes may be more readable. In fact, it depend on what your boxes means. First example used a logic similar with the [numeric file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation), so with some systems it may be easier this way, while if every combinaison you have to show cannot be systematized then you might love the other one better.

Good luck and have fun!